# Sum multidimensional array elements if they have an duplicate

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array like this:

```
array = [[3, 'name'],[4, 'lastname'],[2, 'name'],[4, 'lastname']]
```

I need to sum the values if they have equal second element:

```
array = [[5, 'name'],[8, 'lastname']]
```

I tried to sort array by alphabetic order, I know there won't be more than one duplicate, and then if item is equal to next one sum their values, else do nothing. Maybe the condition should be stringified, this is just to show what I tried...

```
for(var n=0; n<finish.length; n++) {
    if(finish[n][1] === finish[n+1][1]) {
      finish[n][0] += finish[n+1][0];
    } else {
      finish[n][0] = finish[n][0];
    }
  }
```

The loop returns this error: `Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to summarise the data into an object. Use `Object.values` to convert the object into array

```js
let array = [[3, 'name'],[4, 'lastname'],[2, 'name'],[4, 'lastname']];

let result = Object.values(array.reduce((c, v) => {
  if (c[v[1]]) c[v[1]][0] += v[0];     //Add the first element if already exist
  else c[v[1]] = v;                    //Assign the value if does not exist
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Hi! What if this is to sum based on an additional criteria or group by an additional column? Not sure if this would be something for a new question...

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to get the desired output:

```js
let array = [[3, 'name'],[4, 'lastname'],[2, 'name'],[4, 'lastname']];

let map = ((m, a) => (array.forEach(c => {
   let [num, str] = c;
   m.set(str, (m.get(str) || 0) + num);
}), m))(new Map(), array);

let result = [...map.entries()].map(([a, b]) => [b, a]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I thank you for your great answer here, Mohammad. the only one worked for me! I would like to add something to it if you'd allow me. if someone want to sum the data dynamically and its default value in the original array is Nan, this wouldn't work fully until you make an If condition checking if(isNan(arraynum)) then assign arraynum =  0; else arraynum = value; before you attempt to sum results of same index, because it won't do it coz of Nan entries.
thank you and bless you <3

Answer (score 0):

You go up to n< length, but you reference an index of n+1 in

```js
if(finish[n][1] === finish[n+1][1])
```

So, in this case, once you get to n = 3, the n+1  part is referencing an element that is not defined, and thus the error.

To fix this, you need to go up to (n < length-1)