# How to sum/group 2d array by multiple "columns/criteria" using reduce() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've been dancing around with this, but can't figure out how to add a column or criteria.
This groups by the first "column", but how to make it group also by the last column?

This is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49839101/11832197):

```js
let array = [[3, 'name', 'old'],[4, 'lastname','young'],[2, 'name', 'old'],[4, 'lastname','old']];

let result = Object.values(array.reduce((c, v) => {
  if (c[v[1]]) c[v[1]][0] += v[0];     //Add the first element if already exist
  else c[v[1]] = v;                    //Assign the value if does not exist
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

**Expected Result**

```
result = 
[
 [5, 'name', 'old'],
 [4, 'lastname','young'],
 [4, 'lastname','old']
];
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is expected output by grouping by first and third column?

Comment: Hi, @KrzysztofSafjanowski! Thanks for answering! They're about to close this one, but I've added the expected output above. Thanks.

Comment: [There is a proposal to extend Javascript's `Array` with a `groupByToMap` method to allow for grouping semantics of the kind you require](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/groupByToMap). It's not supported in Apps Script yet but you might be able to find a polyfill and use it as a drop in replacement.

Comment: Thanks, @TheAddonDepot! I'll read it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, as a simple modification, for example, how about using the values of columns "B" and "C" as a key of the object of `reduce` as follows?

#### Modified script:

```js
let array = [[3, 'name', 'old'], [4, 'lastname', 'young'], [2, 'name', 'old'], [4, 'lastname', 'old']];

let result = Object.values(array.reduce((c, v) => {
  const k = v[1] + v[2];
  if (c[k]) c[k][0] += v[0];
  else c[k] = v;
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

- When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

  ```
    [
      [ 5, 'name', 'old' ],
      [ 4, 'lastname', 'young' ],
      [ 4, 'lastname', 'old' ]
    ]
  ```

Comment: @onit Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is this what you are looking for?

```
function teste() {
  let array = [[3, 'name', 'old'], [4, 'lastname', 'young'], [2, 'name', 'old'], [4, 'lastname', 'old']];

  let result = Object.values(array.reduce((c, v) => {
    if (c[v[1]]) c[v[1]][0] += v[0]; else c[v[1]] = v;
    if (c[v[2]]) c[v[1]][0] += v[0]; else c[v[2]] = v;                               
    return c;
  }, {}));

  console.log(result);
}


Execution log
2:03:43 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:03:43 PM  Info    [ [ 7, 'name', 'old' ],
  [ 7, 'name', 'old' ],
  [ 12, 'lastname', 'young' ],
  [ 12, 'lastname', 'young' ] ]
2:03:44 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Hi, @Cooper! Thanks for your answer. It should be summed by 2nd and 3rd columns. So, 1st resulting row would be ```[5, 'name', 'old']```. 2nd row =  ```[4, 'lastname', 'young'],``` and so on. Thanks a lot.